# Solve $x$ for $0.0000004x^3 -0.001x^2 +1.6 x - 400 = 200$

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

The question reads as follows:

> A accountant tells a writer that he can calculate the gain (or loss)
>   in function of the sold books with the following formula:
>
> $$f(x)= 0.0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x-400$$

The question is "how many books does the writer need to sell to make a $200\,$€ profit"?

I already got this far (if I am correct).

\begin{align}
    &0.0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x-400 = 200\\
\iff &0.0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x = 600\\
\iff &0.001x ( 0.0004x^2 -x +1600) = 600\\
\iff &x ( 0.0004x^2+1600 -x ) = 600\,000 \\
\iff &x( (0.02x+40)(0.02x-40) -x ) = 600\,000
\end{align}

I probably already made a mistake somewhere but I can't see where. I also know that the answer should be $500$, but I don't find the right way.

Comment: I suggest you multiply through by, say, $10^7$ to get all coefficients integers. Then divide through by $4,$ you should have $x^3 - A x^2 + B x - C = 0$ for (large) integers $A,B,C.$ The good news is that there is, evidently, an integer root. I'm not sure what you did, you do need to get the entire polynomial on one side, equal to zero.  After the edit by JnxF, it appears you never did gather all terms on one side of the equals sign.

Comment: After this $$    0,0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x = 600 $$ the very next step should be $$    0,0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x - 600 = 0 $$

Comment: I then got x³ -2 500 x² + 4 000 000 x -1 500 000 000 =0 But i do not see a root :S

Comment: Or do i just find the Discriminant for the (-2500x²+4 000 000 x - 1 500 000 000) part and for a second 'forget' about the x³ ..

Comment: I do not usually do this trick: to make the zeroes less of a problem, try the substitution $x = 1000 t.$ KEEP THE CUBE. What is the equation that we get for the new variable $t?$ It will be possible to divide through by $10^9$ and get either integers or half-integers

Comment: I really don't see where you are going with this , sorry! 

I am at a point where i indeed have x³-ax²+bx-c=0 with large... (very large) numbers)

Comment: First thing I'd do is get rid of those dang decimals: $0.00000004 = 4*10^{-8}$.  $0.001 = 10*10^{-4}$.  and $1.6 = 160 = 10^{-2}$ so this becomes $f(100x) = 4x^3 - 10x^2 + 160x -400$.  Solve for $f(Y) = 200$ and divide Y/100.

Comment: First off, thanks for showing your effort, +1. Secondly, this question is not about differential equations, I adjusted the tags for you. Lastly, regarding the actual question, I honestly do not see some really nice way of solving this. I mean there is a formula for cubic polynomials, but it seems extreme to use. Another way, which feels slightly like cheating is to plot the function and see that there is a root $x\approx 500$, and then test if it indeed is a root. Otherwise, use rational root theorem to test for rational roots.

Comment: @Eff, both answers below use a linear substitution to get rid of all the annoying zeroes. I would say that is the point of this particular question, starting with euros, it may be more convenient to write the condition in kilo-euros

Comment: Thanks everybody so much for helping! I think i got it now and I think i would be able to solve something similar on the test if only i can perform the right magic and substitutions to get a 'simple' enough equation.

Comment: @WillJagy: Kilo-books, but yes, I think you are right.

Comment: @BrianTung that explains it. I was trying to decide between kilo-euros and micro-euros. This is what comes of not really reading the words in the questions. On the other hand, I am not going to read more of them in the future than i do now; that would be work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start from this:

$$
0.0000004x^3−0.001x^2+1.6x−400=200
$$

Subtract $200$ to both sides to get

$$
0.0000004x^3−0.001x^2+1.6x−600=0
$$

Substitute $u = 0.001x$ to obtain*

$$
400u^3-1000u^2+1600u-600 = 0
$$

Divide by $200$:

$$
2u^3-5u^2+8u-3 = 0
$$

Using the rational root theorem, possible rational roots are $\left\{\pm 3, \pm \frac{3}{2}, \pm 1, \pm \frac{1}{2}\right\}$ (although physically, only positive roots make sense).  We find that $u = \frac{1}{2}$ is a solution:

$$
2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+8\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-3 = \frac{1}{4}-\frac{5}{4}+4-3 = 0
$$

Since $u = 0.001x$, $x = 1000u = 500$.

---

*It's worth pointing out a motivation for this particular substitution.  One is, as Will Jagy points out, to get rid of the annoying decimals.  But further, we observe that the coefficients go down geometrically as the exponent goes up; this suggests that a substitution for a constant ratio will resolve the disparity in scale.  We have a cubic ($x^3$) coefficient of $4 \times 10^{-7}$ and a constant ($x^0$) coefficient of $6 \times 10^2$; this suggests a constant (log) ratio of $\frac{(-7)-2}{3-0} = -3$—i.e., $u = 10^{-3}x$.  Indeed, in this case, this substitution "evens out" the coefficients and leads to a tractable cubic (with respect to rational roots, that is).

Answer (score 3):

$$x^3 -2500 x^2 + 4 000 000 x -1 500 000 000 =0 $$
Let
$$  x = 1000 t    $$
$$ 1000000000 t^3 - 2500000000 t^2 + 4000000000 t - 1500000000 = 0   $$
$$ 10 t^3 - 25 t^2 + 40 t - 15 = 0   $$
Divide by $5,$
$$ 2 t^3 - 5 t^2 + 8 t - 3 = 0.   $$
NOW you need to find the "rational roots" for this $t$

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned something cool! You let $x=1000t$ in order to have less rational roots to check; doing such a substitution only affects the coefficients of the non-constant terms

Answer (score 1):

To clear the decimals, you can define $x=100y$.  It is usually not useful to factor with a constant on the right, so you should start with 
$$0.0000004x^3-0.001x^2+1.6x-400 = 200\\
.4y^3-10y^2+160y-600=0\\y^3-25y^2+400y-1500=0$$
Now you can try factors of $1500$ looking for integer roots, and find $y=5, x=500$ is the only real solution.  Clearly if $y \ge 25$ the left side will be positive, so there aren't too many to try.